# Drupal 7 pager from module fuction not displaying in page.tpl

Tags: theming, 7, paging

I have a function *mymodule_submissions* in my module which fetches rows from mymodule_table and prints as table theme with pager. Its working fine if I define a menu link in my module to call that function. Pager not printing when I call the same function from a page.tpl.

```
function mymodule_submissions() { 

   $query = db_select('mymodule_table', 'uf');
   $query = $query->condition('uid', $user->uid)
             ->fields('mytable', array('id', 'name', 'createdtime'))
             ->orderBy('createdtime', 'DESC')->limit(3);
   $results = $query->execute();
   $header = array('ID','Name','Created Time');

   $rows = array();

   foreach($results As $result) {
      $rows[] = array( $result -> id, $result -> name, $result -> createdtime,);
   }

   $output .= theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows,) );

   $output .= theme('pager');
   return $output;
}
```

From page.tpl, I am calling this function link below

```
print render(mymodule_submissions());
```

Anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think you should really consider the power of Views for your query and your pager. From what I can see, you're using a custom table. Exposing your table to Views is quite easy (a good tut can be found here: http://www.sitepoint.com/exposing-tables-views-drupal-7/)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `->extend('PagerDefault');`

```
$query = db_select('mymodule_table', 'uf')->extend('PagerDefault');
```

I find the [examples module](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) really useful.  They have a pager example.

For what its worth I think using the Drupal db API with theming is a perfectly valid way forward that has a lot of strengths: it's efficient, flexible, powerful and you can put it in version control.  Obviously you should use the best thing for the situation.